# Replace double quotes with space using sed or tr command in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, unix

I am writing a script in **batch file for Windows**. I want to replace double quotes with space in a file.

Input file `File1.txt` contains:

> "05-09-2017", "07:00:14"
>   "05-09-2017", "07:00:14"
>   "05-09-2017", "07:00:14"
>   "05-09-2017", "07:00:14"
>   "05-09-2017", "07:00:14"

I have tried the following:

```
tr.exe "\"" " " < "File1.txt" >  "File2.txt"
```

The above line gives me an error like

> tr.exe: too many arguments

And I have also tried:

```
sed.exe "s/\"/ /g" "File1.txt" >  "File2.txt"
```

The above gives me an error like

> sed.exe: can't read >: Invalid argument

I need output file like this:

> 05-09-2017 , 07:00:14
>   05-09-2017 , 07:00:14
>   05-09-2017 , 07:00:14
>   05-09-2017 , 07:00:14
>   05-09-2017 , 07:00:14

Can you please look into this.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed "s/\x22/ /g" "input.txt" 

tr "\""" " "   < "input.txt"
tr """" " "    < "input.txt"
tr \""  " "    < "input.txt"
```

Comment: Okay, I give up; I tried all sorts of parms for `tr` before seeing this answer; how/why does the first parm have the "extra" double quote:  `"\"""`?

Comment: @MarkStewart, It is probably the worst way of writing it, but you need to include the additional quote (or escape a quote) to ensure the redirection operator is out of a quoted area so `cmd` handles it and it is not seen as a `tr` argument (same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58661959/2861476))

Answer (score 0):

Why using Unix tools and not native Windows commands for this simple task?

```
@echo off
if not exist "File1.txt" goto :EOF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
del "File2.txt" 2>nul
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("File1.txt") do (
    set "Line=%%I"
    set "Line=!Line:"= !"
    echo !Line!>>"File2.txt"
)
endlocal
```

**Note:** The command **FOR** as used here skips empty lines and lines starting with a semicolon.

I would replace the double quotes by nothing which means deleting the space character after equal sign.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Actually I am trying to grep some portion from a very big log file.Thats why i am using unix commands.Any way i will try this

Comment: To avoid possible interference with a trailing number I'd insert the stream number `echo !Line!1>>"File2.txt"`

Comment: @Jayesh you can avoid cmd quirks with PowerShell. It's much more powerful and predictable than cmd