# GNU awk on win-7 cmd, won't redirect output to file

Tags: awk, cmd, windows-7, output, io-redirection

If relevant I have GNU awk V 3.1.6 downloaded directly from GNU pointed source in sourceforge.

I am getting a page of URLs using wget for windows. After prcoessing the incoming file, I reduce it to single line, from which I have to extract a key value, which is quite a long string. The final line looks something like this:

```
<ENUM_TAG>content"href:e@5nUtw3Fc^b=tZjqpszvja$sb=Lp4YGH=+J_XuupctY9zE9=&KNWbphdFnM3=x4*A@a=W4YXZKV3TMSseQx66AHz9MBwdxY@B#&57t3%s6ZyQz3!aktRNzcWeUm*8^$B6L&rs5X%H3C3UT&BhnhXgAXnKZ7f2Luy*jYjRLLwn$P29WzuVzKVnd3nVc2AKRFRPb79gQ$w$Nea6cA!A5dGRQ6q+L7QxzCM%XcVaap-ezduw?W@YSz!^7SwwkKc"</ENUM_TAG>
```

I need the long string between the two " signs.

So I use this construct with awk

```
type processedFile | awk -F "\"" "{print $2}"
```

and I get the output as expected

```
href:e@5nUtw3Fc^b=tZjqpszvja$sb=Lp4YGH=+J_XuupctY9zE9=&KNWbphdFnM3=x4*A@a=W4YXZKV3TMSseQx66AHz9MBwdxY@B#&57t3%s6ZyQz3!aktRNzcWeUm*8^$B6L&rs5X%H3C3UT&BhnhXgAXnKZ7f2Luy*jYjRLLwn$P29WzuVzKVnd3nVc2AKRFRPb79gQ$w$Nea6cA!A5dGRQ6q+L7QxzCM%XcVaap-ezduw?W@YSz!^7SwwkKc
```

but when I run the same command with output redirected to a file, such as

```
type processedFile | awk -F "\"" "{print $2}" > tempDummy
```

I get this error message:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `>' for reading (Invalid argument)
```

I am thinking the \" field separator is causing me some grief and making the last " character as a non-closed string value, but I am not sure how to make this right. The same construct runs on my centos box perfectly well by the way.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. I tried reading all the readme files I could find but none of them touches the output redirection.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have problems with how `cmd` parser deals with where quoted areas start/end. What `cmd` sees is

```
awk -F "\"" "{print $2}" > tempDummy
       ^-^^-^          ^-------------
       1  2            3
```

that is, three quoted areas. As the `>` falls inside a quoted area it is not handled as a 
redirection operator, it is an argument to the command in the rigth side of the pipe.

This can be solved by just escaping (`^` is `cmd`'s general escape character) a quote to ensure `cmd` properly generates the final command after parsing the line  and that the redirection is not part of the `awk` command

```
type processedFile | awk -F ^"\"" "{print $2}" > tempDummy
                               ^^ ^..........^
```

Or you can reorder the command to place the redirection operation where it could not interfere

```
type processedFile | > tempDummy awk -F "\"" "{print $2}"
```

but while this works using this approach may later fail in other cases because the `awk` code (`{print $2}`) is placed in an unquoted area.

There is a simpler, standard, portable way of doing it without having to deal with quote escaping: instead of passing the quote as argument it is better to use the `awk` string handling and just include the escape sequence of the quote character

```
type processedFile | awk -F "\x22" "{print $2}" > tempDummy
```

Comment: This solution works in Cmder with cmd task in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You were close.  The issue here is that you are mixing `awk` redirection with `cmd` one.

For completness sake I'm using `MSYS2 awk` version (version should not matter in this issue):

```
awk --version
GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)
```

Windows version is in this case irrelevant - will work both on Win7 and Win10

Your command:

```
type processedFile | awk -F "\"" "{print $2}" > tempDummy
```

uses  `>` which you expect to be a `cmd.exe` redirection, but awk expects a file, thus you get the error:  ``` awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file ``>' ```

### 1) Fixing the redirection

You can **fix** that by doing the redirection directly at `awk`:

```
type processedFile | awk -F "\"" "{ print $2 > "tempDummy"; }"
```

### 2) Using awk to read the file

The `type` command is here superfluous as you can use directly `awk` to read the file:

```
awk -F "\"" "{ print $2 > "tempDummy"; }" processedFile
```

**Don't forget note:** What is important to note is that GNU utils are case sensitive but the default filesystem settings at windows is case-insensitive.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. They work the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @mc-nd , I found another solution.
This should work as well:

```
type processedFile | awk -F '^"' '{print $2}' > tempDummy
```